# QlikView Make button unclickable if no selections are made

Tags: qlikview

I would like to be able to make my button unclickable / grayed out if no selections are made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the button properties > general tab > enable condition.

Use the follwing code:

```
not isnull(GetCurrentSelections())
```